# Regular Expressions for Floats

Tags: java

I am trying to get the regular expression for floats to work. I keep getting an error

> Cannot invoke matches(String) on the primitive type float.

Any help? I'm kinda lost.

```
System.out.print("Enter $ amount of loan:");
payment = scanner.nextFloat();

while (!Regulations.paymentmatch(payment)) {
    System.out.println("Information Not Correctly Entered");
    System.out.printf("Please try again: ");
    payment = scanner.nextFloat();
}
```

---

```
public static boolean paymentmatch(float a) {
    return  a.matches("\\d+.?\\d{2}");
}
```

Comment: `Cannot invoke matches(String) on the primitive type float"` it's telling you , you need a string , so do `String.valueOf(a).mat..`

Comment: Regular Expressions work against Strings. You need to convert your float into a String and check against the regex.

Comment: Why not just use `scanner.hasNextFloat()`?

Comment: @PavneetSingh: Doing `String.valueOf(a)` on a `float` would be pretty silly if the goal is to validate a float, since by definition it's going to be valid.

Comment: use #nextLine or #hasNextFloat (if other data doesn't matter) instead of #nextFloat, you're telling the scanner to go until it finds a floating, not searching for it yourself

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow the user to type a non-float value and then read it and tell them it's not a valid float value, you can't use `nextFloat` to read it, because...if it's not a valid float value, it won't work.

Either use `hasNextFloat`, which will tell you whether the scanner can read a `float` (but won't let you tell the user they typed something that wasn't a float), or use `nextLine` to read whatever they typed (as a `String`) and then validate that (via `matches`).